# ConEmu Transparent Background?

Tags: console, transparency, conemu

There's a transparency option but that makes the whole window transparent. Is there a way to get the background to be transparent and not the borders nor text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible in the current version. May be later (exists in RoadMap), but this requires much coding...

Comment: they 'could' possibly just copy the code from Console2, which already has this available and is open source. Mintty also offers the same option and is open source too.

Comment: I also don't know why but my ConEmu window disappears every once in a while, for some reason...

Comment: Console2? Really? Show screenshot. Also, ConEmu can't disappears without reason. May be your shell was terminated. Not ConEmu.

Comment: Haha it's interesting how I said "They", but then I noticed your icon, checked out your account and found out that you're the developer! But yea, console2 can do it and that's the only leverage it currently has over your emulator. It's presented in their one and only screenshot here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: ConEmu does the same thing with transparency. I can draw in photoshop anything... Provide your own screenshots where Console is good and ConEmu transparency is worse.

Comment: **And** you may easily to be convinced, that borders and text **are** transparent on SF screenshot. What leverage you are talking about, heh? :-P

Comment: I just tested it, and yes you're right. Console transparency is the same as ConEmu, and I do sincerely apologize. :) mintty is also the same thing.